# Converting from MOQ to NSubstitute mocking a class level field / variable

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I am new to NSubstitute and 30 minutes in I can't find how to mock class level fields / variables.

In MOQ I would do this:

```
public class PlanControllerTest
{

    Mock<IDataAccessTemplate> _template = new Mock<IDataAccessTemplate>();

    [TestMethod]
    public void BadDataResponse()
    {
       Mock<ISomethingElse> other = new Mock<ISomethingElse>();

    }

}
```

However refactoring to NSubstitute I use:

```
public class PlanControllerTest
{

    ???? _template = Substitute.For<IDataAccessTemplate>();

    [TestMethod]
    public void BadDataResponse()
    {
       var other = new Substitute.For<ISomethingElse>();

    }

}
```

It is that class level declaration that I can't figure out.
I've been through the basic tutorial here:

http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/

and the closest I find via Google is:

[How to set value to a local variable of a class using NSubstitute in TestProject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131007/how-to-set-value-to-a-local-variable-of-a-class-using-nsubstitute-in-testproject)

Surely this is not the first time this has been asked??

Comment: Using the dynamic keyword is an option. Visual Studio should you give a clue of the return type.

Comment: If the docs were updated to `ISomeInterface substitute = Substitute.For<ISomeInterface>()` would that help? My only reservation for that is that `var` seems to be the most common way this is written in C#, and maybe the docs should reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [NSubstitute](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/8fa1588a48da18741b1d2444c1b78f8c3a8dc11a/Source/NSubstitute/Substitute.cs) code. The implementation of **For <T>** will return **T**. So using IDataAccessTemplate should compile.